# Find number of 1's in binary representation of fibonacci(1) to fibonacci(N)

Tags: algorithm, binary, fibonacci

Given a Number N, calculate fibonacci(1) to fibonacci(N). Convert each of these N numbers to binary and append them together. We have to return the number of 1's in this final string.

**My Thoughts:**
One straightforward way will be to calculate Fibonacci(i) for each number i convert it to binary and calculate the number of 1's in it and sum up for i=1 to N.
Could there be a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Seems like a good candidate for: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Initial count = 2 (since sum of 1s in binary 1 and 2 are one each)

Iterating i from 3 to N:
if(i % 2 == 0) inc count by 2
else inc count by 1

Example: For 5th term of Fibonacci is 8 (if you consider Fibonacci series as 1,2,3,5,8 ....if it is 1,1,2,3,5 then you've to increase count by another 1).
For 1 -> 1, 2 -> 10, 3 -> 11, 5 -> 101,
8 -> 1000. Assuming we've appended it as a string (110111011000) total is 7. If you iterate from 3 to 5 count (2 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 7). If you want to use string compulsorily then I guess yeah you can add number of 1s in the string by iteration it as you said.